# Is it still true that each onion relay keeps an open TLS connection to every other relay? Why?

Tags: relays

The [original paper](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a465464.pdf) describing Tor says this on section 4:

> Each onion router maintains a TLS connection to every other onion router.

That paper is from 2004, when there was a much smaller number of relays on the network. [Now there are more than 5000](https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html).

- Is it still 100% true that relays form a complete graph at all times?
- Wouldn't that number of simultaneous connections exceed some OS limit on number of open sockets or something like that?
- Does it impose a performance penalty on relays?
- Is there any privacy consideration that requires those connections to exist at all times?
- What kind of messages do those relays exchange when they're not part of the same circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor relays do not maintain open connections to every other relay.  Relays create connections to other relays when asked to by a client, or when they need to connect to retrieve some information (like getting new Consensus documents from a Directory Cache.